# iOS Local Push Notification using Cellular Data

Tags: ios, pushkit, networkextension

I'm are working on a project that's required to be in a fully isolated VPN network.
I'd like to find if there's any special entitlement for iOS apps that provide sending and receiving push notifications without using APNs servers.

I found a topic under Network Extension in Apple documentation "Local Push Connectivity" but it requires the iOS device to be using a specific SSID that requires WiFi to work as mentioned in Apple documentation:
"When a user’s iOS device joins a Wi-Fi network that has an SSID matching a configured SSID in your NEAppPushManager instance, the system launches your app extension and instantiates the NEAppPushProvider subclass within that app extension."
Source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity

I also found a sample code from Apple's documentation, "Receiving Voice and Text Communications on a Local Network"
But the sample mentioned that it "Provide voice and text communication on a local network isolated from Apple Push Notification service by adopting Local Push Connectivity."
Source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity/receiving_voice_and_text_communications_on_a_local_network

is there a way to receive Push Notifications & VoIP Notifications in a local and isolated network using VPN and cellular data only ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15 has added the ability to watch for specific LTE networks as well as specific WiFi SSIDs to enable the NEAppPushProvider. See the `matchPrivateLTENetworks` property on [NEAppPushManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapppushmanager) -- as of this writing the documentation for it is very sparse, but the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity/receiving_voice_and_text_communications_on_a_local_network) you linked to has been updated to support private LTE networks.